# how to hide ad when the internet is not available

Tags: android

I am making an application in which i am giving an add.But even when the internet connection not available,it takes space in the view/layout.I just want to hide it and to not allow it taking space in layout/view when the internet is not available.This is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/explain_QuestionImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1.0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="1.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.0dip"
                android:fadeScrollbars="true"
                android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:fillViewport="true" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/explain_question"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/explain_QuestionImageView"
                    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/question_text"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@color/question_text1" />
            </ScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/explain_separator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5.0dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/explain_question"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="" />

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="100.0dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1.0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="1.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="1.0dip"
                android:fadeScrollbars="true"
                android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:fillViewport="true" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/explain_explaination"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/explain_separator"
                    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_green" />
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- </ScrollView> -->

    </FrameLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a1501e5633125fb"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 123456789ABCDEF" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL_Buttons1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40.0dip"
            android:layout_above="@id/ad"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#ff777777"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/PrevExplainationButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2.0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/ibtn"
                android:onClick="onPrevExplainationButtonClick"
                android:text="Previous" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/NextExplainationButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="2.0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/ibtn"
                android:onClick="onNextExplainationButtonClick"
                android:text="Next" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

please tell me how to do it.

Comment: On your code somehow check if internet is available or if there is a connection and then set the visibility of your add view to gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, to put a more concrete example you can test for connection and then setting the visibility to `gone`:

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    yourAddView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni == null) {
      // There are no active networks.
      //Set the visibility to "gone".
      //You can set visibility to gone here or when the function returns,
      //that is why there is a return false and true. 
      myView.setVisibility(8);
      return false;
    } else
    return true;
}
```

Also you need to add these permissions to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To Check Data Connection available or not, use following function

Also add permission in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

In the activity:

```
public boolean netCheckin() {

try {

    ConnectivityManager nInfo = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    nInfo.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();

    // Log.d(tag, "Net avail:"
       // + nInfo.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting());

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        //Log.d(tag, "Network available:true");

        return true;
    } else {
    // Log.d(tag, "Network available:false");

        return false;
    }

} catch (Exception e) {

    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    ad.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        ad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
        ad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Kotlin version of Abed Putra's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473675/13855858)

```
MobileAds.initialize(this)
var madView = findViewById<AdView>(R.id.adView)
madView.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
madView.adListener = object: AdListener(){
    override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: Int) {
        madView.visibility = GONE
    }
}
```